# How to see the SQL queries generated by NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, sql-server-profiler

I'm using SQL server express edition with ASP.NET MVC, there is not a profiler in express editions so I can't see the queries generated by NHibernate. I'm concerned about the performance and how I can see the queries without a profiler?

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at [nhprof](http://nhprof.com/)? It's a profiler for NHibernate written by Ayende and should (I think) work with express. There's a trial version you can test with.

Comment: It's a fantastic product so it's well worth checking out. Apart from giving you the sql it will also look for potential issues and warn you about them.

Answer (score 3):

You could [enable logging](http://www.davesquared.net/2008/01/viewing-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myselft, but theoretically you could use [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx)

Comment: IntelliTrace is available only in Visual Studio Ultimate Edition.

Comment: @Darin He does mention that uses express edition of SQL Server, not visual studio

Comment: @archil, you are right. I didn't read carefully. Unfortunately the system doesn't let me remove my downvote until your answer is edited as it is older than 6 minutes.

Comment: @archil, well, in this case I downvoted by mistake and I don't think this downvote is deserved. Especially that it probably brought someone else's.

Comment: I'm using express edition of VS too. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Upvoted for being a relevant answer and to hopefully get this positive so there is no downvote chain gang on this for no reason.